# How to enable CurlHttpClient for WAMP in PHP 7.4+?

Tags: php, curl, wamp, wampserver

I'm trying to open the index_dev.php file for a site on my Wampserver and I'm getting this error:

```
Internal Server Error - PHP Warning - Configure the "curl.cainfo", "openssl.cafile" or "openssl.capath" php.ini setting to enable the CurlHttpClient
```

I tried to do some research on how to enable curl on WAMP, but all of the info I was seeing was for PHP 5.x

As far as configuring, I don't have a clue what I should do to the "curl.cainfo", "openssl.cafile" or "openssl.capath" settings in my php.ini files.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Have you edited any configuration? Appears you're missing your CA certificate for SSL. You can either self-sign a certificate and update your configuration as your error message tells you or disable SSL locally, ie connect on `80` (http) instead of `443` (https).

Comment: Also, [this guide for self-signed certificates](https://www.saotn.org/dont-turn-off-curlopt_ssl_verifypeer-fix-php-configuration/) looks perfectly fine to me after googling the error.

Comment: @Jaquarh I haven't done any configuration other than changing some memory limits, max execution times, etc. Already connecting over port 80, so I don't think this is it

Comment: The error is pretty much specific, you're missing your CA certificates which you can just self-sign and add to your configuration. Unsure why they're missing in the default installation but clearly, they are. Unsure why they're needed for insecure HTTP connections but Apache2 seems to want them present. Configure them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html and download the latest `.pem` file.

Copy the `.pem` file to ..... well I put mine in `C:\wamp64\bin\php` called `cacert.pem`

This contains a whole bunch of certificates and because the file is created by Mozilla we sort of trust it.

Now using the WAMPManager, edit your current `php.ini` file by

```
left click wampmanager -> PHP -> php.ini
```

Find this parameter, it will be commented out with a `;`

```
;openssl.cafile=
```

Change it to

```
openssl.cafile="c:/wamp64/bin/php/cacert.pem"
```

Save the edit, and then restart Apache to activate the change

Comment: That did it. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You may need to check for the latest .pem file every so often and update it